# Uploading File on GAE using gwt-upload

Tags: java, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

Can someone know how to upload files using gwt-upload implementation at http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/ on Google Application  Engine.

Answer (score 0):

The [download page](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/Downloads?tm=2) lists the `gwtupload-gae` artifacts, which are "GwtUpload for GAE servers".

Comment: Can i use this implementation on GAE http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted

Comment: My problem is how to handle the upload on the GAE server

Answer (score 0):

See the second post by dindeman: [GWTUpload using GAE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwtupload/MNAz7UHXfm4).

The following link may also help shed light on what's currently going on with `GWTUpload-GAE` in relation to Google's new FileService API: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwtupload/SYV6AGp7qkY.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't work: when I try to access the bytes, I find the size is 0

```
public class UploadFileHandler extends AppEngineUploadAction {
  @Override
  public String executeAction(HttpServletRequest request, List<FileItem> sessionFiles) throws UploadActionException {

    for (FileItem item : sessionFiles) {
      String name = item.getName();
      byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(item.getInputStream());
    }
  }}
```